# Python Plotly Dash - How do I access updated component value without using callback?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

When you enter something other than "test" in the input box, and press enter, the label should change to reflect that input.

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


markerNameInp = dbc.Input(id='markerNameInp',placeholder='Enter name..',
                     style={'min-width':'150px','width':'15%',
                            'margin-right':'20px','display':'inline-block',
                            'margin-bottom':'10px'}, value = 'test')
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(style={'font':'Frutiger Linotype, sans-serif',
                             'margin-left':'50px','margin-right':'50px'},
    children=[
        html.Div([markerNameInp]),
        dbc.Button('Enter',id='enter',
                            color = 'primary',
                            className='mr-1',
                            style={'height':'40px'}),
        html.Div(id="output")
        ])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='enter', component_property='n_clicks')]
)

def func(enter_clicks):
    return dbc.Label(markerNameInp.value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to access an updated component value by accessing the Python object defined in the layout (`markerNameInp.value`). This is because each user accessing the Dash app will interact with it differently, and the state is stored on the client-side (the user's browser) rather than server-side (where the app is running, and where the Python object `markerNameInp` is located).

In your use case, it is possible to access the `value` property of `markerNameInp` by using `dash.dependencies.State`, which does not trigger the callback when the component is updated, but the value can still be captured.

Here's the updated code:

```py
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State


markerNameInp = dbc.Input(
    id="markerNameInp",
    placeholder="Enter name..",
    style={
        "min-width": "150px",
        "width": "15%",
        "margin-right": "20px",
        "display": "inline-block",
        "margin-bottom": "10px",
    },
    value="test",
)

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    children=[
        html.Div([markerNameInp]),
        dbc.Button("Enter", id="enter", color="primary", className="mr-1"),
        html.Div(id="output"),
    ],
)


@app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    [Input("enter", "n_clicks")],
    [State("markerNameInp", "value")]
)
def func(n_clicks, marker_value):
    return dbc.Label(marker_value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

(the bootstrap code was changed in order to reflect best practice, and some styling was removed for simplicity).