# Access plotly figure relayout data in notebook

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter, plotly-python

Is there a way to access a figure relayout data in jupyter notebook/lab?

What I mean is the following:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Define the figure
fig = (go.Figure(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[0, 1, 2, 3],
        y=[-1, 1, -2, 2]
       )
    )
    .update_layout(
        modebar_add=['drawrect']
    )
)

# Show the figure
fig.show()
# Now do some drawing in the figure here! 

# Next cell I would like to access the shapes
```

I know this is possible using dash callbacks as in [here](https://dash.plotly.com/annotations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily if you're willing to use [Plotly Dash](https://plotly.com/dash/) in Jupyterlab with [JupyterDash](https://medium.com/plotly/introducing-jupyterdash-811f1f57c02e) and the `mode` attribute of `app.run_server()` set to `'inline'`.

Below is an image of the resulting notebook with full information of a drawn line in the second cell. The complete setup with your figure is included below, and builds on one of the many examples from [`Image annotations with Dash`.](https://dash.plotly.com/annotations)

If this is something you can use, I'd be happy to explain things in more detail.

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, ClientsideFunction
import dash_html_components as html
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import json

app = JupyterDash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

fig = (go.Figure(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[0, 1, 2, 3],
        y=[-1, 1, -2, 2]
       )
    ))

fig.update_layout(dragmode="drawline")
config = {
    "modeBarButtonsToAdd": [
        "drawline",
        "drawopenpath",
        "drawclosedpath",
        "drawcircle",
        "drawrect",
        "eraseshape",
    ]
}

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H4(
            "Draw a line"
        ),
        dcc.Graph(id="graph1", figure=fig, config=config),
        # dcc.Markdown("Characteristics of shapes"),
        html.Pre(id="annotations-data-pre"),
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output("annotations-data-pre", "children"),
    Input("graph1", "relayoutData"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def on_new_annotation(relayout_data):
    if "shapes" in relayout_data:
        global relayoutdata
        relayoutdata = json.dumps(relayout_data["shapes"], indent=2)
        return ''
    else:
        return dash.no_update

app.run_server(mode='inline', port=8002)
```

Comment: Thank you @vestland! This is actually the approach I am currently using (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70645614/python-jupyterdash-unable-to-access-callback-modified-objects) to read/write to disk for recording callback actions). I don't have any problem with such solution, yet I was wondering if this was possible without dash and jupyter-dash dependencies and writing/reading to disk